# PHP- Parsing words from a string without spaces?

Tags: php, regex

My webpage has a variable, $currentPage. This is a string of the php token name of the page I'm currently on.

Example: All categories under the user section have names such as:
uAdminNew, uAdminEdit, ect..

I would like for a way to parse out the uAdmin and just determine what is the last word (New and Edit) and call upon functions from there.

I have my navigation system working through these names, therefore I can't change the names or I would to make it easier to parse. Such as adding delimiters.

Is this something only Regex can solve or is there a simpler solution I'm missing? If this is Regex could you explain or provide a link as to how I would go about using it to test against a specific list of strings? I'm very new to it.

Comment: Is `uAdmin` ever different? if not then there's no need for regex: `str_replace('uAdmin', '', $currentPage)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the pagename always start with uAdmin? If so, you could split the string by "uAdmin" with [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php):

```
$page   = 'uAdminEdit';
echo explode('uAdmin', $page)[1]; //Output: Edit
```

Or simply remove "uAdmin" with [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$page   = 'uAdminEdit';
echo str_replace('uAdmin', '', $page); //Output: Edit
```

Comment: This worked really well! Simple enough to get the job done! I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

For example, so:

```
$str = 'uAdminEdit';    
$ar = preg_match('/([A-Z][^A-Z]+$)/', $str, $m);    
echo $m[1]; // Edit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the section after uAdmin, use the regex capture groups

```
preg_match('/uAdmin(.*)/', $sub, $matches);
echo $matches[1]
```